# Endless GC_FOR_ALLOC after resize one ImageView

Tags: android, android-layout, android-imageview, infinite-loop

I got endless GC_FOR_ALLOC in my log cat as below:

```
32ms, total 32ms
07-01 12:23:28.946  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1994K, 32% free 18349K/26896K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
07-01 12:23:29.116  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3006K, 32% free 18381K/26896K, paused 20ms, total 20ms
07-01 12:23:29.376  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4671K, 33% free 18284K/26896K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
07-01 12:23:29.496  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1898K, 32% free 18379K/26896K, paused 18ms, total 18ms
07-01 12:23:29.606  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1994K, 32% free 18349K/26896K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
07-01 12:23:29.806  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3006K, 32% free 18381K/26896K, paused 15ms, total 16ms
07-01 12:23:30.086  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4671K, 33% free 18283K/26896K, paused 17ms, total 19ms
07-01 12:23:30.206  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 2035K, 33% free 18242K/26896K, paused 14ms, total 15ms
07-01 12:23:30.316  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1994K, 33% free 18212K/26896K, paused 11ms, total 12ms
07-01 12:23:30.486  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3007K, 33% free 18245K/26896K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
07-01 12:23:30.736  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4359K, 33% free 18146K/26896K, paused 17ms, total 18ms
07-01 12:23:30.856  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1898K, 33% free 18242K/26896K, paused 16ms, total 17ms
07-01 12:23:30.966  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1994K, 33% free 18212K/26896K, paused 15ms, total 15ms
07-01 12:23:31.136  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 3006K, 33% free 18245K/26896K, paused 20ms, total 21ms
07-01 12:23:31.396  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 4359K, 33% free 18146K/26896K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
07-01 12:23:31.516  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1898K, 33% free 18242K/26896K, paused 17ms, total 17ms
07-01 12:23:31.636  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowongan D/dalvikvm﹕ GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 1994K, 33% free 18212K/26896K, paused 19ms, total 20ms
07-01 12:23:31.816  14905-14905/com.dodosocial.lowon
```

After tracing down the error, I found it's because I have programmatically modified the height of an ImageView.
Here is the code I used:
MyActivity.java

```
private ImageView mImageUserProfile;
private Bitmap mBitmapIcon;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    mImageUserProfile = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.login_icon);
    mImageUserProfile.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mBitmapIcon = CommUtils.getUserProfileBitmap();
            if(mBitmapIcon!=null) {
                setupIcon();
            }
        }
    });
}

private void setupIcon() {
    int bmHeight = mBitmapIcon.getHeight();
    int bmWidth  = mBitmapIcon.getWidth();

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mImageUserProfile.getLayoutParams();
    layoutParams.height = layoutParams.width*bmHeight/bmWidth;
    mImageUserProfile.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

    mImageUserProfile.setImageBitmap(mBitmapIcon);
}
```

After I removed the height-changing code like below, the GC_FOR_ALLOC thing is gone

```
private void setupIcon() {
  int bmHeight = mBitmapIcon.getHeight();
  int bmWidth  = mBitmapIcon.getWidth();

  /*
  RelativeLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)mImageUserProfile.getLayoutParams();
  layoutParams.height = layoutParams.width*bmHeight/bmWidth;
  mImageUserProfile.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);
  */

  mImageUserProfile.setImageBitmap(mBitmapIcon);
}
```

Comment: By changing the layout params in onGlobalLayout, you're probably causing an infinite loop of layouts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @GabeSechan said in a comment on your question, you are causing an infinite loop because you don't remove your layout listener.

By changing the height of an `ImageView`, you invalidate its measurement which causes a layout pass. The system will re-layout and then re-trigger the `GlobalLayoutListener`, which then re-triggers your code to change the height...which causes another layout... etc.

You should be OK if you just remember to remove the listener before changing the layout.

Using your code it would look like this:

```
mImageUserProfile
    .getViewTreeObserver()
    .addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
        @Override
        public void onGlobalLayout() {
            mBitmapIcon = CommUtils.getUserProfileBitmap();
            if(mBitmapIcon!=null) {
                mImageUserProfile
                    .getViewTreeObserver()
                    .removeGlobalOnLayoutListener(this);

                setupIcon();
            }
        }
    });
```